# Can i add a cube to the top of every selected face of an object using Python?

Tags: scripting

I was hoping i could add cubes to random faces of a terrain, then link their object data and sculpt a tree to easily populate a scene. Would this be possible with Python scripting?

Comment: The answer to any "Can you do it with Python" question is yes :) But are you aware of the particle system and the ability to have any mesh (or a mesh from a group) as "hair"? works well for grass and forests. Can you provide more details of what you are trying to achieve? Maybe upload a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use particle systems for that. You can even put multiple models of trees in a collection and then distribute them randomly while picking them randomly from that collection:

[image]